# Healchcare ai load error: R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the healthcare  ai package after updating the version of R:

```
install.packages("healthcareai")
library(healthcareai)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘healthcareai’ in
>   loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
>   vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘ddalpha’

I tried installing the 'ddalpha' but another error

> /var/folders/m8/y4hvcvrx4233n10636g64mlh0000gn/T//ccM1OugK.s:6664:2:
>   error: unknown directive
>           .stabd  68,0,144
>           ^ /var/folders/m8/y4hvcvrx4233n10636g64mlh0000gn/T//ccM1OugK.s:6670:9:
>   error: unsupported directive '.stabs'
>           .stabs  "cvkernsm_:F(0,3)",36,0,105,*cvkernsm*
>
> make: *** [depth.fd.o] Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed for package
>   ‘ddalpha’
>   * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/ddalpha’
>   Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘ddalpha’ had
>   non-zero exit status

Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are installing `ddalpha` from source on OS X. Have you tried installing the pre-built package from CRAN instead?

Comment: Works fine for me. I installed it using RStudio.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using RStudio as well. Would you please share the commands for installing the pre-built package.

Comment: I'm using the following commands: install.packages("ddalpha")

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
        binary  source needs_compilation
ddalpha  1.3.1 1.3.1.1              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: y

Comment: Selecting "n" in the previous question fixes the issue.